# Where to find descriptions of Ubuntu's packages (e.g. zlib1g, build-essential)?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I'm learning about Unix and as part of that, I'd like to have some idea of what all these packages I've been told to install are. I've found that Googling the package name doesn't always reveal anything useful (at least not immediately). Is there a command that would display any documentation or summary of a package, given its name?

**EDIT** - The distribution is Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: It depends on the package manager, and so on the Linux distribution you are using (I suppose you talk about Linux, right?)

Comment: @enzotib Yeah. Good point, I edited the question to include that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a package description with one of these commands (the APT command for installable packages, the `dpkg` command for installed packages):

```
apt-cache show package-name
dpkg -s package-name
```

You can get the list of installed files with

```
apt-file list package-name
dpkg -L package-name
```

In particular grepping this command for `/man/` or `/bin/` can give you information about available man pages and binaries.

The package documentation should be in

```
/usr/share/doc/package-name/
```

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
dpkg --list | grep 'package name'
```

you get a (very) brief description (one-liner, in case apt-cache show is to elaborate).